# Validate count() constraint in many to many relation before saving an instance in django

Tags: python, django, validation, django-models, django-forms

I would like to prevent a save in a django model when a certain constraint is not met and give a validation error so that a django staff user knows what went wrong.

The constraint is the `count()` from an intermediate table specified using the `through` parameter.

**models.py**:

```
class Goal(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
  goals = models.ManyToManyField(Goal, through=UserProfileGoals, blank=True)

class UserProfileGoal(models.Model):
  goal = models.ForeignKey(Goals)
  user_profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)

class UserGoalConstraint(models.Model):
  user_profile = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile)
  max_goals = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

So the `UserGoalConstraint.max_goals` gives me the number of the maximum definable `UserProfile.goal` which are stored in the `UserProfileGoal` model (same `UserGoal` can be stored more often to the `UserProfile`)

I have read and tried solutions from several posts, which are using ModelForm's `clean()`, Model's `clean()` and `pre_save` signal events,

but the actual problem I have is, how do I know if it is just an update or a new database entry, because

```
class UserProfileGoal(models.Model):
  goal = models.ForeignKey(Goals)
  user_profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)

  def clean(self):
    goal_counter = self.user_profile.goals.count() + 1

    try:
      qs = UserGoalConstraint.objects.get(user_profile=self.user_profile)
    except UserGoalConstraint.DoesNotExist:
      raise ObjectDoesNotExist('Goal Constraint does not exist')

    if goal_counter > qs.max_goals:
      raise ValidationError('There are more goals than allowed goals')
```

does not really work, as `clean()` can also be an update and the +1 gives me a wrong result which leads to the ValidationError.

My client should use the django-admin interface to add goals to the user profile directly via an Inline:

**admin.py:**

```
class UserProfileGoalInline(admin.TabularInline):
  model=UserProfileGoal

class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)
  ...
  inlines = [UserProfileGoalInline, ]
```

So he needs to be nicely informed when he adds to many goals to a user profile.

Maybe I am missing something obvious on how to solve this problem...?
I am looking for a working and somehow user friendly solution (= get informed in admin interface).

[UPDATE]:
I tried know to check wether it is created or not with the `self.pk is None` trick at the beginning of the `clean()`

```
if self.pk is not None:
  return  # it is not a create
...
```

I thought that would deal with the issue...
However, in the admin inline, when the staff user adds more than one goal at the same time, the clean() does not recognize these. Debug output shows for 2 goals added, that the goal counter holds the same number even the second entry should have one more and should give an validation error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @zaidfazil for a starting solution:

```
class UserProfileGoalForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = UserProfileGoal
    ...

  def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(UserProfileGoalForm, self).clean()
    if self.instance.pk is not None:
      return cleaned_data
    user_profile = self.cleaned_data.get('user_profile')
    goal_count = user_profile.goals.count()
    goal_limit = UserGoalConstraint.objects.get(user_profile=user_profile).max_goals # removed try catch for get for easier reading
    if goal_count >= goal_limit:
      raise ValidationError('Maximum limit reached for goals')
    return cleaned_data
```

However, this does not handle the inline in the UserProfile admin interface: `clean()` won't handle correctly if you add more than one `Goal` at the same time and press save.

So I applied the `UserProfileGoalForm` to the inline and defined [`max_num`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.get_max_num) :

```
class UserProfileGoalInline(admin.TabularInline):
  model=UserProfileGoal
  form = UserProfileGoalForm

  def get_max_num(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    if obj is None:
      return
    goal_limit = UserGoalConstraint.objects.get(training_profile=obj).max_goals
    return goal_limit # which will overwrite the inline's max_num attribute
```

Now my client can only add at maximum the `max_goals` value from the `UserGoalConstraint`, and also a possible admin form for `UserProfileGoal` will handle the constraint:

```
class UserProfileGoalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  form = UserProfileGoalForm
```

Answer (score 0):

You could handle it in `ModelForm` `clean` method,

```
class GoalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Goal
        .....

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(GoalForm, self).clean()
        if self.instance.pk is not None:
            return cleaned_data
        goal_limit = self.user_profile.usergoalconstraint.max_goals
        goal_count = self.user_profile.goals.count()
        if goal_count >= goal_limit:
            raise ValidationError("Maximum limit reached for goals")
        return cleaned_data
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion on my real example. But I am struggling already with the class `GoalForm`. `Goal`s can be created without a `UserProfile`. I think you mean `UserProfileGoal`? Also this approach does not work, see the UPDATE section in the question. However the `ModelForm` brought me the solution, which I will post as an answer.